# Madge skips imported typescript file

Tags: madge

I want to print a Javascript dependency graph using madge. It prints all dependencies of a given file successfully. Unfortunately, it skips the imported `.ts` files and subsequently does not show them in the graph.

Here is my config (`.madgerc`):

```
{
    "fileExtensions": ["js", "ts"],
    "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.json",
    "graphVizOptions": {
        "G": {
            "splines": "ortho"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2018",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "rootDir": "../"
  }
}
```

I run madge like so:

```
madge src/main/path/to/file/view-model.js --warning --debug -i ~/Desktop/graph/view-model.png
```

It prints:

```
✔ Image created at /Users/patrick/Desktop/graph/view-model.png

✖ Skipped 1 file

./transform-sponsor
```

`transform-sponsor` is imported in my Javascript file like so:

```
const {transformSponsors} = require('./transform-sponsor');
```

So my question is, why does madge skip my typescript file. Even though I specifically added a `tsconfig` file as explained in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge#configuration)?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `--extensions ts` to the runned script

Answer (score 0):

In my experience madge process JavaScript - Files much better then Typescript files. The solution for me was to use madge on the transpiled JavaScript - Files rather than on the original Typescript - src - Files.

I don't really know the answer to your question but I assume that madge is made originally for JavaScript - Files and TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript thus not so important for the madge - developers (Please don't throw bananas at me when it's not true)